# How to have Jenkins automatically clone a maven job when a SVN branch is created?

Tags: svn, maven, jenkins

Our project uses maven to build, Subversion as code repository, and Jenkins for continuous integration. When a new branch is created (typically during a release), we have to create a new job in Jenkins by hand.

Is it possible to tell Jenkins to automatically create job for newly created branches (and not legacy ones) ?

Comment: I think this is a task for a Groovy script. (Scripler Plugin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is doable. You would have to create a SVN hook, and then using Jenkins CLI (you could use groovy) or Jenkins REST API you could have to create the job for the project.

Here's an example using [Sinatra + GitHub](https://github.com/versapay/hudson-github-autobranch)
Another using [Groovy + GitHub](http://entagen.github.com/jenkins-build-per-branch/)