# Trigger job in Jenkins automatically when new branch is created in SVN

Tags: jenkins

I need to trigger a Jenkins job automatically whenever a new branch is created in SVN. How can I do it? Please help.

Comment: Do you mean you want to set up a new job (maybe based on a master-template) for the new branch, or really just run an existing job?

Comment: I would want to set up a new job for the new branch based on the master template.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have Jenkins automatically clone a maven job when a SVN branch is created?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976996/how-to-have-jenkins-automatically-clone-a-maven-job-when-a-svn-branch-is-created)